# TcpClient.ConnectAsync throws SocketException Connection refused on Linux

Tags: c#, docker, sockets, .net-core, debian

I have a `TcpListener` listening on `localhost`. Next application creates `TcpClient` and connects to the server.

Both server application and client application are written in .net core 3.1 and published as self contained apps.

Everything works fine on `Windows`.

On `Linux` (`Debian` inside a `Docker` image, latest `Debian` image) the `TcpClient` throws `SocketException`. Both applications are in the same Docker image and in the same folder.

> System.Net.Internals.SocketExceptionFactory+ExtendedSocketException
> (111): Connection refused 127.0.0.1:5005    at
> System.Net.Sockets.Socket.BeginConnectEx(EndPoint remoteEP, Boolean
> flowContext, AsyncCallback callback, Object state)    at
> System.Net.Sockets.Socket.UnsafeBeginConnect(EndPoint remoteEP,
> AsyncCallback callback, Object state, Boolean flowContext)    at
> System.Net.Sockets.Socket.BeginConnect(EndPoint remoteEP,
> AsyncCallback callback, Object state)    at
> System.Net.Sockets.Socket.BeginConnect(IPAddress address, Int32 port,
> AsyncCallback requestCallback, Object state)    at
> System.Net.Sockets.Socket.BeginConnect(String host, Int32 port,
> AsyncCallback requestCallback, Object state)    at
> System.Net.Sockets.TcpClient.BeginConnect(String host, Int32 port,
> AsyncCallback requestCallback, Object state)    at
> System.Net.Sockets.TcpClient.<>c.b__28_0(String
> targetHost, Int32 targetPort, AsyncCallback callback, Object state)
> at
> System.Threading.Tasks.TaskFactory`1.FromAsyncImpl[TArg1,TArg2](Func`5
> beginMethod, Func`2 endFunction, Action`1 endAction, TArg1 arg1, TArg2
> arg2, Object state, TaskCreationOptions creationOptions)    at
> System.Threading.Tasks.TaskFactory.FromAsync[TArg1,TArg2](Func`5 beginMethod, Action`1 endMethod, TArg1 arg1, TArg2 arg2, Object state,
> TaskCreationOptions creationOptions)    at
> System.Threading.Tasks.TaskFactory.FromAsync[TArg1,TArg2](Func`5 beginMethod, Action`1 endMethod, TArg1 arg1, TArg2 arg2, Object state)
> at System.Net.Sockets.TcpClient.ConnectAsync(String host, Int32 port)

I can confirm that `TcpListener` has started successfully (logging in app).

Server code (logging omitted):

```
var listener = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Loopback, 5005);
listener.Start();
var client = await listener.AcceptTcpClientAsync();
using (var networkStream = client.GetStream())
{
  ...
}
```

Client code:

```
var client = new TcpClient(AddressFamily.InterNetwork);
// also tried "localhost" instead of ip address
var connectTask = client.ConnectAsync("127.0.0.1", 5005);
var isConnectTaskFinished = await Task.WhenAny(connectTask, Task.Delay(timeout, m_cancellationTokenSource.Token)) == connectTask;
...
client.Close();
```

I'm not sure what can be wrong and how to find the root cause. Do I need to allow the port on `Debian` or set some permissions for both apps?

Comment: Have you exposed the port through Docker? Is the client also running in Docker?

Comment: @Llama The client is also running in Docker.

Comment: Is it running in the same Docker image? If not, "localhost" isn't going to cut it.

Comment: @Llama both applications are in the same Docker image and in the same folder.

Comment: If you're listening on "localhost" are you also using this name to connect the client?

Comment: @Llama I've tried connect to "localhost" and also tried IP address "127.0.0.1". In both cases it throws the same exception.

Comment: Is your [loopback interface up](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/217071)?

Comment: @StephenCleary loopback interface wasn't up. I've tried make changes mentioned in the linked question but it doesn't help.

Comment: @user2250152: Sorry, I don't know the specifics of Linux network interface management. But perhaps you could ask a different question (maybe on the Unix site) now that you know what the problem is.